# SQL Server: is there a function to determine if all specified values are equal?

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I'm looking for an "ALL_EQUAL" function like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Field = Table1.Field
INNER JOIN Table3.Field = Table1.Field 
WHERE ALL_EQUAL(Table1.Value, Table2.Value, Table3.Value)
```

I could certainly do this by creating a huge "AND" chain. But in the  environment I want to execute this query I have to compare up to 7 values, so an AND chain would be massive (restructuring the tables is not an option at the moment).

Is there any elegant way to do this?

Comment: You could create a function so that the chain of ANDs would be removed elsewhere.

Comment: In order to save HUGE chain of 7 columns, you will have to use dynamic sql, where you'll query the columns of your tables, and build the where condition.

Comment: There would be 6 comparisons, I wouldn't call this massive.

Comment: Depends on how the rest of the query is structured. You could `UNPIVOT` them so that they all occupy a single column then check whether `MIN()` and `MAX()` over that column are equal.

Comment: Is `value` a number?

Comment: Value is a varchar

Comment: You're trying to solve the problem where there is none. 7 values being equal is not huge chain and. It's still small query. To make sure 7 values are all equal you need 6 equals: v1=v2, v2=v3,v3=v4,v4=v5,v5=v6,v6=v7. All other equals are implied.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a custom expression, but it won't simplify the things much. For example:

```
CONCAT(@Value1, @Value2, @Value3, @Value4) = REPLICATE(@Value1, 4)
```

Here you can try it:

```
DECLARE @Value1 TINYINT = 5
       ,@Value2 TINYINT = 5
       ,@Value3 TINYINT = 5
       ,@Value4 TINYINT = 3;

SELECT IIF(CONCAT(@Value1, @Value2, @Value3, @Value4) = REPLICATE(@Value1, 4), 1, 0)

GO

DECLARE @Value1 TINYINT = 5
       ,@Value2 TINYINT = 5
       ,@Value3 TINYINT = 5
       ,@Value4 TINYINT = 5;

SELECT IIF(CONCAT(@Value1, @Value2, @Value3, @Value4) = REPLICATE(@Value1, 4), 1, 0)

GO


DECLARE @Value1 TINYINT = 5
       ,@Value2 TINYINT = NULL
       ,@Value3 TINYINT = 5
       ,@Value4 TINYINT = 5;

SELECT IIF(CONCAT(@Value1, @Value2, @Value3, @Value4) = REPLICATE(@Value1, 4), 1, 0)

GO



DECLARE @Value1 VARCHAR(8) = 5
       ,@Value2 TINYINT = 5
       ,@Value3 TINYINT = 5
       ,@Value4 TINYINT = 5;

SELECT IIF(CONCAT(@Value1, @Value2, @Value3, @Value4) = REPLICATE(@Value1, 4), 1, 0)

GO
```

This could reduce a little bit the length, but you must test how it is affecting performance comparing it with the standard solution using `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use 1 expression, you could try below method. But I don't think it's better than using separate comparison (Value1 = Value2 AND Value1 = Value3 AND Value1 = Value4...). If you have 7 values, it's 6 comparisons.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Field = Table1.Field
INNER JOIN Table3.Field = Table1.Field 
WHERE Table1.Value = ALL(
      SELECT Table2.Value UNION ALL
      SELECT Table3.Value)
```